# How to find Q-Matrix

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

Hello I have following example and dont really know how to solve it:

I need to find a Q-matrix for Markov Chain with 4 states , I = {1,2,3,4} with following conditions:

1. There is no escape from state 2
2. You cannot reach 3 from state 1
3. The element in the third row and second column of the jump matrix is 1/9.
4. The waiting time in state 4 is exponentially distributed with parameter 8.

I arrived at $Q = \begin{pmatrix}
q_{11} & q_{12} & 0 & q_{14}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
q_{31} & q_{32} & q_{33} & q_{34}\\
q_{41} & q_{42} & 0 & -8\\
\end{pmatrix}$

I dont know how else to proceed, calculating the jump matrix is easy

The Jump Matrix would be $\Pi = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \frac{q_{12}}{-q_{11}} & 0 & \frac{q_{14}}{-q_{11}}\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{q_{31}}{-q_{33}} & \frac{1}{9} & 0 & \frac{q_{34}}{-q_{33}}\\
\frac{q_{41}}{8} & \frac{q_{42}}{8}& 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$
Where the rows of the jump matrix add up to 1 but I still find there are too many unknowns..?

Comment: What have you tried?  Some of these are easy and determine particular cells of the matrix.  What does that look like? What decisions are you left with?

Comment: Perhaps edit that into your question.   I am not so sure about $q_{43}=0$ as it may depend on whether $q_{14}>0$ or $q_{14}=0$.  Apart from that, you seem to have flexibility on the other values subject to rows summing to $0$ and non-negative values except on the main  diagonal.  Perhaps you are allowed to use your own choices

Comment: Thank you for editing the question: it is now much better

Comment: You cannot say much more about $Q$ based on the fourth condition. The only thing you can add is that the columns sum to 0; i.e. $Q\mathbf{1}=0$.